# Retrieve data from Firebase with complex model and print it inside adapter

Tags: java, android, json, firebase

How can i get branch `Choix` from `Sondage` and print it into my Adapter class.

[image]

Here's my ModelClass

**AccueilItem**

```
public class AccueilItem {

private String idSondage;
private String publisher;
private String titreSondage;
private ArrayList<ChoixItem> choix;

public AccueilItem() {
}

public AccueilItem(String idSondage, String publisher, String titreSondage, ArrayList<ChoixItem> choix) {
    this.idSondage = idSondage;
    this.publisher = publisher;
    this.titreSondage = titreSondage;
    this.choix = choix;
}

public String getIdSondage() {
    return idSondage;
}

public void setIdSondage(String idSondage) {
    this.idSondage = idSondage;
}

public String getPublisher() {
    return publisher;
}

public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
    this.publisher = publisher;
}

public String getTitreSondage() {
    return titreSondage;
}

public void setTitreSondage(String titreSondage) {
    this.titreSondage = titreSondage;
}

public ArrayList<ChoixItem> getChoix() {
    return choix;
}

public void setChoix(ArrayList<ChoixItem> choix) {
    this.choix = choix;
}
}
```

**ChoixItem**

```
public class ChoixItem extends ArrayList<ChoixItem> {

private String idChoix;
private String titreChoix;

public ChoixItem() {
}

public ChoixItem(String idChoix, String titreChoix) {
    this.idChoix = idChoix;
    this.titreChoix = titreChoix;
}

public String getIdChoix() {
    return idChoix;
}

public void setIdChoix(String idChoix) {
    this.idChoix = idChoix;
}

public String getTitreChoix() {
    return titreChoix;
}

public void setTitreChoix(String titreChoix) {
    this.titreChoix = titreChoix;
}
}
```

Inside my main class, I retreive my data successfully, but i can't get the branch Choix to print it

**AcceilActivity**

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            accueilItems.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                AccueilItem accueilModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(AccueilItem.class);
                accueilItems.add(accueilModel);
            }
            accueilAdapter = new AccueilAdapter(AccueilActivity.this, (ArrayList<AccueilItem>) accueilItems);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(accueilAdapter);
            accueilAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(AccueilActivity.this, "Error:" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

If anyone can help, I would be so grateful, i'm suck in this for 2 days.

Comment: Your model classes doesn't match the JSON in Firebase database, you will get the data in `onDataChange` but it won't map into your model.

Comment: Question has wrong codebase implemented

Comment: Can you please give me some solution ? how my model classes doen't match the JSON ? what should i do ?

Comment: I edited my JSON tree structure, can you please help me to achieve and resolve my problem ? thank you

Comment: I have create a very simple JSON to Java POJO to make you understand how JSON to be converted/mapped into Java. https://codebeautify.org/json-to-java-converter/y22c81f30

Comment: Thank you for your help, i see what wrong with my code, the variables wasn't the same in JSON and Java, tnx bro

Comment: So have you solved the problem? Please respond using @AlexMamo